# Remove an array value from mongodb collection document, sailsjs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, sails.js, sails-mongo

I have an array like this on under user collection
[image]

How can i remove a single value from this array by using sails.js code

also i need to remove all post id from every users document if a post is deleted, is there any simplest and fastest way to remove from all documents too??

Comment: Could you paste ur models code? Post , user... everything what u are using in this operation?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of easy ways to do it if you're using the built-in ORM "Waterline", and they are basically equivalent.

The first is to run `Model.update()` and overwrite the array with the new value.

```
Model.update(id, { likes : [/* new array value */] }).then(...)
```

The other is to 1) find the object 2) pull the value off the array 3) save:

```
Model.findOne(id, function(err, document){
  if(err) // handle err case
  else {
    document.likes = document.likes.filter(value => value !== 'stringToRemove')
    document.save(function(err, saved){
      ... // do more stuff
    })
  }
})
```

Finally, unless you're using it for a very simple app, I cannot recommend using Waterline ORM with MongoDB. Save yourself a heap of headache and use [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com).